# How to remove the WordPress generated title tag for specific custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

OK so I have inherited a website built by another developer and the code is all over the place. It's a directory site organized by state / city and to make sure that the same city name can appear under different states as unique posts, some funky rewrites and redirects have been implemented.

Long story short, because of these url rewrites, All In One SEO won't work with the custom post type.

I managed a workaround by creating a second header.php for the custom post type and implementing the following:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
    // get the state name
    $state = '';
    $states = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'state' );
    if( $states ) {
        $state = ', ' . strtoupper( $states[0]->description );
    }
    $city_name = get_the_title();
    $title = $city_name . $state;
?>

<title>Cash for Gold Near <?php the_title(); ?> - Find Gold Buyers Near <?php the_title(); ?></title>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It generates the appropriate title tag but then I run into the problem of their being TWO title tags - the custom one and the WP generated one.

Is there a way to get rid of the WP generated title tag (and also the meta description) for a specific custom post type?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Cynthia

Comment: You need to find the other template that is creating the title. Wordpress doesn't just do it, there has to be a function similar to the one you have that is generating it. I would start by looking in header.php.

You can check for the post type before choosing which one to display.

Comment: The auto generated title is implemented by the following function in functions.php:

function av_theme_slug_setup() 
{
   add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}

I can't strip it out because then it strips it out site wide. How can I disable that particular function for a custom post type?

Comment: I added an answer with code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check for the post type where the other title tag is being generated:

```
if( !is_singular( 'post-type-slug' ) ){
     //write normal post title
}
```

You should replace 'post-type-slug' with the slug used for your post type. You can do the same thing in the other area to only show the title if it IS the right post type:

```
if( is_singular( 'post-type-slug' ) ){
     //write custom post title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<title>Cash for Gold Near <?php echo $title; ?> - Find Gold Buyers Near <?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Comment: That won't work because of how the previous developer handled the custom post type URL rewrites. It's really skewed, The code I am using above works fine. I just need to disable the WP generated title tags and meta descriptions so that I don't have two of each.

Comment: You could find the code that is generating the other title and place it in a conditional block.

If post type is custom, echo $post->title otherwise echo get_the_title()